# Searchkick: RSpec setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, opensearch, searchkick

I have successfully integrated Searchkick to my Rails 7 app in order to allow the user to search and filter Products.
I am starting to write out the RSpec tests now and I'm very confused about the right setup.

The [doc](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#rspec) says:

Add to your spec/spec_helper.rb:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    # reindex models
    Product.reindex

    # and disable callbacks
    Searchkick.disable_callbacks
  end

  config.around(:each, search: true) do |example|
    Searchkick.callbacks(nil) do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

And use:

```rb
describe Product, search: true do
  it "searches" do
    Product.create!(name: "Apple")
    Product.search_index.refresh
    assert_equal ["Apple"], Product.search("apple").map(&:name)
  end
end
```

Factory Bot: Use a trait and an after create hook for each indexed model:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :product do
    # ...

    # Note: This should be the last trait in the list so `reindex` is called
    # after all the other callbacks complete.
    trait :reindex do
      after(:create) do |product, _evaluator|
        product.reindex(refresh: true)
      end
    end
  end
end

# use it
FactoryBot.create(:product, :some_trait, :reindex, some_attribute: "foo")
```

However, it's unclear to me what exactly these do, and why this is the recommended setup.
Particularly, my questions are:

1. If I make the `Product.reindex` only to run before each `suite` as the doc suggests, then I see these warnings when running my tests that call the `search`: `[searchkick] WARNING: Records in search index do not exist in database: Product 1234, ...`, as if the search index didn't clear from one test to another. What's the way around that? I noticed that if I put `Product.reindex` in a `before(:each)` block for all my searchkick-related unit tests, it suppresses those warnings but makes the tests REALLY slow even if I just have 3 Products per unit test at most. What am I missing?
2. Why does the doc suggest adding `Searchkick.callbacks(nil) do` block AS WELL as calling `product.reindex(refresh: true)` AS WELL as `Product.search_index.refresh`? Isn't the first line supposed to enable callbacks which should keep the index updated already?
3. Why am I still seeing **`Enqueued Searchkick::ReindexV2Job`** logs printed out during the tests even if I disabled callbacks? Update: I figured out this is because in another model (Address) I have a callback that does:  `self.owner.reindex(mode: :async)`. I guess this is not affected by the `Searchkick.disable_callbacks` option.

Comment: I have the exact same questions. In my case, with Minitest